# Is there a way to make Github branch wait for multiple reviews to be approved for a pull request?

Tags: github

Generally, a Github branch goes to "Approved" state when at least one person approves the changes. But sometimes a branch may be needed to be reviewed by more than one person and it could only be merged when everybody approves.

Is there a way to override default behavior of Github to setup a branch not to go to "Approved" state until all reviewers have approved the changes? Basically I don't want the branch to show up in green until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub has the ability to [require multiple reviewers](https://blog.github.com/2018-03-23-require-multiple-reviewers/).

[image: multiple]

Answer (score 1):

GitHub does not currently support this functionality.

Comment: I un-ticked your answer since it seems GitHub have support for this now.